# Counting operations (FLOPS)

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

There are 2 definitions of floating point operations (i.e. flops):

1) one floating point addition, subtraction, multiplication or division
2) one multiplication followed by one addition (e.g. a + b * c)

I've seen the second definition applied to analyzing the complexity of Gaussian Elimination with Back Substitution. In Gaussian Elimination, to reduce a matrix to upper triangular form, the operations consist of adding a multiple of one row to another row. So, in the operations, a multiplication is always paired with an addition.

I don't understand in how you would be able to apply the second definition to numerical methods/algorithms where there are additions that are not paired with a multiplication (e.g. a + b + c + de)

Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplication is free (if you need it), but if all you want to do is add, just set $c=1$, then $a + bc$ yields $a+b$.

Similarly, if all you want to do is multiply, just set $a=0$, then $a + bc$ yields $bc$.

Thus, it can perform $3$ tricks: $\;\,a+b,\;\,bc,\;\,a+bc$.

The reason for the second definition is that, presumably, some chips have the $a+bc$ operation built in as a single operation, so for these chips, if there is a step in the algorithm which is naturally expressible as $a+bc$, only one operation is needed for that step, instead of two.

When performing just additions, or just multiplication, there's no gain, but no loss either. It's the combined operation, when applicable, that yields a reduced operation count (for those steps which can be so expressed).

Comment: "some chips have the $a+bc$ operation built in as a single operation" Do you have a reference for this claim? I don't know much about such instructions, but it sounds very very strange if some chip uses the same time for addition as for addition plus multiplication.

Comment: No specific reference, no. In general, the floating point chip is faster than the CPU, so while $a+bc$ requires two floating point operations (fist compute $bc$, then add $a$), the CPU force the FPU to do both and return the final result without sending back the intermediate results, the idea being that the result can be obtained in $1$ CPU cycle.

Comment: But in any case, it was not a claim -- I said "presumably". The presumption was a proposed justification for the second definition, else why would the operation $a+bc$ count as a single flop, rather than two.

Comment: Thank you the info, that makes sense. Also found some nice info on Wiki  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS#FLOPS_per_cycle_for_various_processors which has a list over FLOPS per cycle for several different cpu families.

Comment: @quasi I wasn't asking for a justification for the second definition. All of the articles I've read that use the definition use it to estimate the complexity of numerical algorithms like row reducing a matrix or computing a polynomial. In those algorithms it happens that the operations are all of the form a + bx. The articles do not mention what the flop count is for additions not paired with a multiplication is. For example if a + bc is one flop what would the flop count be for (a + bc) + c + d? Do we count a + bc as one flop and count c and d as 2 additional flops?

Comment: @user137481: Yes, by the second definition, $(a+bc)+ c + d$ would be $3$ flops. A combo of the form $a+bc$ would be $1$ flop. A pure addition, not paired with a multiplication, would be $1$ flop. A pure multiplication, not paired with an addition, would also be $1$ flop. But if an algorithm (e.g., Gaussian elimination) is order-of-magnitude dominated by combination steps, then for comparison purposes, the pure additions and pure multiplications can be ignored.